# Virtual Directory Creation

Tags: asp.net

Guys, I want to write a program in ASP.NET to create virtual directories on the hosting server. Please tell me how to program this?

Answer (score 2):

To tackle this, you need to [impersonate an administrator](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/1572.aspx), or at least a user with sufficient rights. After that, use something like [the code provided here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/CreateVirtualDirs12052005234144PM/CreateVirtualDirs.aspx) (other examples available, [try Google](http://www.google.nl/search?q=IIS+create+virtual+directories+through+code)), or the code provided by Russ C in this thread.

Perhaps too obvious to mention, but I do it anyway: doing so is *dangerous (!!)*.  Make sure to safe-guard your page with more than just a password (i.e., add an ip-address filter to your firewall).

***EDIT:***
The question doesn't seem to be about virtual directories, but just directories. Assuming rights are set correctly, the following should work to create a directory under your current virtual path:

```
string serverVirtualPath = Server.MapPath("~");
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(serverVirtualPath);
dirInfo.CreateSubDirectory("MyImageSubDir");   // returns a DirectoryInfo object
```

Answer (score 1):

It's different for IIS 6 and 7, and I don't know if this will work in ASP.Net or if it has to be done from a Winform/Console application (because of role security)...

If 6 use:

```
DirectoryEntry deIIS = new DirectoryEntry( "IIS://" + Environment.MachineName + "/W3SVC/1/Root" );
DirectoryEntry deNewVDir = deIIS.Children.Add( vdName, deIIS.SchemaClassName.ToString() );
deNewVDir.CommitChanges();
deIIS.CommitChanges();
```

For 7:

```
ServerManager iisManager = new ServerManager();
iisManager.Sites["Default Web Site"].Applications.Add("/myVirtualDirectory", installationDirectory);
iisManager.Sites["Default Web Site"].Start();
iisManager.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Sir, I'm the owner of my website. I've all the rights of administration. Actually I want to create a administrator panel to create virtual directory for storing images uplaoded by users.

Comment: @Rohan: it doesn't matter that you have all the rights: the ASP.NET user that runs any ASP.NET page has very limited rights. Otherwise, everybody using your pages would be an administrator. For storing uploaded images, you do not need virtual directories, just use `Directory.CreateDirectory` and point it to a location where the ASP.NET user has create-rights.

Comment: @Abel: Dear Abel! I want to say that I've created a back end panel for my website in ASP.NET. I've windows hosting with unlimited space. I've made feature to upload images on my website from back end panel. But those images stored in default directory, so I want to create indivisual directory for different category of images. So tell me that code to create directory automatically

Comment: @Rohan, please see my original answer, I updated it. Question about that answer, are better placed underneath it, or I might not be notified.